# Getting the hierarchical scope from where a function was called

Tags: system-verilog

When calling a function, is it possible for that function to get the hierarchical scope of the location where it was called?

Let me give you an example. I have the following code:

```
package some_pkg;

function void some_function();
  $display("%m");
endfunction

endpackage


module top;
  import some_pkg::*;

  initial
    some_function();

endmodule
```

When running it, it will display "some_pkg::some_function". Is there any way that I can get the function to display "top"? Or if I would have some other sub-module where it is called from, could it display "top.submodule"?

Comment: I think you could do this without resorting to simulator specific functionality be implementing your function in C via VPI - is that an option?

Comment: It is, but I wanted to avoid compiling any extra C code. I am anyway building a layer on top of simulator system functions ($ nc_force/$ signal_force) to handle white box signals and I don't want to implement these as well.  The code will anyway have `ifdefs a plenty.

Comment: Have you found any solutions for this that works with VCS?

Comment: @Ari I don't use VCS.

Comment: I ended up with the exact same issue today when using the `"%m"` or even `svGetScope()` using DPI-C. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454395/getting-the-hierarchical-scope-from-where-a-function-was-called#comment101461532_24459053) below for details if interested, and let me know if you were able to eventually retrieve the current scope as a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be tool specific and requires extra debugger information to dynamically track scopes. Modelsim/Questa has `$stacktrace` that will display the scope and filename/linenumber

Comment: For reference, In VCS it is $stack

Comment: Is there a way to get it programmatically. Say into a string?

Comment: As stated in the original question comments, you could probably use the VPI to get this information. Then it could be returned in whatever form you want.

Comment: Cadence/Xcelium also has `$stacktrace;`. But I have the same question as @Krishna. Is there a way to get that info into a Verilog string? If using VPI, can I please see an example? I tried using `svGetScope()` using DPI-C, but I am facing the same limitation as posted in the original question by @TudorTimi. Is there any way using DPI-C?

Comment: DPI-C by itself wont help. You need to traverse the VPI object model as defined in the LRM  **37.41 Frames**

Answer (score 0):

I kind of got it working using a macro:

```systemverilog
`timescale 1ns/1ns

`define here_str $sformatf("%s::%0d %m", `__FILE__, `__LINE__)
`define here(DUMMY="") $display("I am here: %s", `here_str);

package some_pkg;

  function void some_function();
    $display("%m");
  endfunction

endpackage : some_pkg

module top;
  import some_pkg::*;

  initial begin

    some_function(); // Gives the wrong scope https://stackoverflow.com/q/24454395/1219634
    $stacktrace; // Does not return the stacktrace as a string value

    `here() // This works, but I would rather not use a macro as I
            // would like to make this portable in a package

    $finish;
  end

endmodule : top
```

---

*Tested on Cadence/Xcelium 18.09-s014.*